# How to enable fluentD sumologic plugin

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, fluentd, sumologic

I am trying to forward the logs from fluentD to summologic.

I have the following configuration in fluentd.conf

```
 <source>
  @type forward
  port 24224
  bind 0.0.0.0
</source>

  <match *.*>
      @type sumologic
      endpoint https://collectors.us2.sumologic.com/receiver/v1/http/XXXXX
      log_format json
      source_category AppLog
      source_name FluentD
      open_timeout 10
    </match>
```

While loading the docker contaier I get error as

```
config error file="/fluentd/etc/fluent.conf" error_class=Fluent::ConfigError error="Unknown output plugin 'sumologic'. Run 'gem search -rd fluent-plugin' to find plugins"
```

I request for the help to resolve the issue.

Comment: `fluent-gem install fluent-plugin-sumologic_output`

Comment: @jordanm: I already had it run but I am still getting this